# Excel VBA - generate next empty row number and copy to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

VBA Issue.

I’m a VBA novice, and I’m trying to see if I can get my code to do just a little more for me. 
Currently, the code opens a spreadsheet on my sharedrive, checks for the next empty row, and provides me with row number. For example, I have 39 rows of data, and the 40th row is empty, it give me the number 40.

It currently provides me this number in a msgbox. What I would like it to do is input that number in to a cell on my open worksheet.

The number essentially works as an ID, which also shows us how many ‘complaints’ have been filed.

Any Ideas?

Here is my code currently:

```
Sub LastRowWithData()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ConcernMemosMaster As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set ConcernMemosMaster = Workbooks.Open("N:\myfilepath")
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

ConcernMemosMaster.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox lastRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Just assign the lastRow to whatever cell you want to put it into. Recording a macro or googling should quickly get you the correct syntax.

Comment: Row number is not a very reliable Id - if you delete one or more rows then you would end up with duplicate values. Better to store the Id in a cell or workbook name and increment it each time you read the value.

Comment: `which also shows us how many ‘complaints’ have been filed....` A simple Excel formula `=COUNTA(A:A)` will also give you the number of entries in Col A. And if you have headers in Col A then `=COUNTA(A:A) -1` The same function can be called from VBA as well.

Comment: Hi Tim the reason I want to copy it into a cell is because I do in fact store it in a cell. I also store it in a separate workbook name, and it is also assigned a second ID based on number, data, time, and user.  I'm just interested in taking this value from the other workbook and copying it into a cell.

Comment: What Tim mentions is the problem of duplicate values. Like in your example, it should give you 40 because there are 39 rows. What if later a row is deleted and gives you 40 again?

Comment: It won't get deleted. If I was concerned with that, my question would of been geared towards how to correctly generate unique ID codes. I simply dumbed down the question in order to get help with issue at hand, which is I'm not sure if its possible to have that value generated, then use that value and copy and paste it into the current workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will stick the number of rows + 1 (*your `lastRow` variable*) in the active sheet cell `A1`.

If you wanted it in a different cell than modify the line

`currentSheet.Range("A1") = lastRow`

and replace `A1` with a different cell reference.

Your macro:

```
Sub LastRowWithData()

    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ConcernMemosMaster As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set ConcernMemosMaster = Workbooks.Open("N:\myfilepath")
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ConcernMemosMaster.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    currentSheet.Range("A1") = lastRow

End Sub
```